# Print Table with Value_Counts and Mean

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with columns ['foo', 'bar', 'isodate', 'category', 'size'].   I used

```
print(df['category'].value_counts().to_frame())
```

to get a nice report for my boss.  Now he wants the mean size of each different category.

I used df.groupby['category'].mean() to get the averages but I can't figure out how to make it print alongside the value counts to make a nice table.

What I'd like to see is something like:

```
           Category    Avg
cat_a      281       489884
cat_b      54       8488324
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You just save the average to a new column

```
df['Avg'] = df.groupby['category'].mean()
```

Comment: That didn't work out.  The original dataframe has thousands of rows but only a dozen or so categories.    I ended up creating several series with value counts, mean, min and max and iterating over category to print my table.